# Using Action<T> for an event

Tags: c#, events

I am trying to implement a simple event subscription based on the instructions below:

Write a program for Online Attendance with the following conditions:

- User provides their name as Input and then application show message to “Welcome to their Name”.
- Jack, Steven, and Mathew are banned for the organization. So, when any user enters Jack, Steven, and Mathew as username, the application should raise an event and fire alarm as well as send email to administration.

Here is what I came with :

```
using System;

namespace EventPlay
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.bannedUser += OnBannedName();
            user.newUser();
        }

        public void OnBannedName(string n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Users Found. Sending Email to Administration.", n);
            Console.WriteLine("Email Sent.");
            Console.WriteLine("Warning Alarm Started.");
        }
    }
    class User
    {
        public event Action<string> bannedUser;
        public string Name;

        public void newUser()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, What is your name ?");
            Name = Console.ReadLine();

            if ((Name == "Jack" || Name == "Steven" || Name == "Mathew"))
            {
                bannedUser(Name);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Hello {Name}!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I got the following error and don't understand why neither be able to correct my code.

(line 10)

```
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action<string>"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are calling OnBannedName on that line (`OnBannedName()`), not referring to the function. If you put the function name (no parentheses), it's the equivalent of `new Action<string>(OnBannedName)`, i.e. you are adding a reference to a delegate to OnBannedName to the event (rather than trying to add what is returned from the function).

Comment: Remove the parentheses: `user.bannedUser += OnBannedName;`. With the paranetheses, you *call* the function instead of *referencing* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use parentheses, it means that you are calling method. Method invocation returns value, so in an assignment it uses value returned by the method, which you don't want.

What you want is to assign method itself, which is done by writing method's name without parentheses, so your code should be:

```
user.bannedUser += OnBannedName;
```